# How do I add a device to my Twitter account?

Tags: twitter

My carrier (T-Mobile, UK) is not on the list of carriers that Twitter supports. So I attempted to add my phone using SMS. It looks like it was successful (I received an email suggesting that Twitter has added my phone to the account) but I can't see anything on the [devices page](https://twitter.com/settings/devices) and on the [settings and security page](https://twitter.com/settings/security) it's saying that I still need to add a device.

I've tried submitting something to Twitter support, but it's been over two weeks and there hasn't been a response.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong (aside from having a non-supported carrier)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't see it on the page as the device is supported. You won't be able to update your status via SMS. However, the phone number you added will help you setup login verification(see [this](https://twitter.com/settings/security) page).

For tweeting from your phone it's best to use the Twitter client for your platform or use the mobile site.

Comment: It won't let me select any of the security options, not sms or via the Twitter app